# Multiple urls in a get request with axios.all, how do I match response.data to its appropriate url object?

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios

I am building a tool to use for work. Basically I upload a csv to extract details which will act as parameters in an axios get request.

I am using multiple urls in axios.all, and my problem is I cannot match up the reponse data to each object of that specific url. The details are below with code snippets. I hope I've made it clear enough below, but this has to do with mass requesting many urls at once, and receiving response data. The problem lies in matching up that response data to its correct url from which it was called.

Here we go...to start, I am mapping an array of vehicle data I am uploading from an external csv file. 'resultsArray' is my array and it holds the year, make, model, trim, price, a url to locate the original posting, and location of the vehicle.

```
    let vehicle_specs = resultsArray.map(function(d, index) {
    let values = {
      year: d['Title_name'].split(' ')[0], // Iterate with bracket notation
      make: d['Title_name'].split(' ')[1],
      model: d['Title_name'].split(' ')[2],
      trim: d['Title_name'].split(' ')[3],
      price: d['Title_Price'],
      cl_url: d['Title_Price_url'],
      cl_location: d['Title_Location'],
    }
    return values;
  });
```

I use the new keyword to create an object of the vehicle.

```
      let Vehicle = function(year, make, model, trim, price, url, cl_url, cl_location) {
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.trim = trim;
    this.price = price;
    this.url = url;
    this.cl_url = cl_url;
    this.cl_location = cl_location;
  }
```

I then build the object with a new instance of **Vehicle** and return each vehicle as I need it to be.

```
       let  vehicle_data = vehicle_specs.map(function(s) {
       let url = `http://api.marketcheck.com/v2/stats/car?api_key={}&ymm=${s.year}|${s.make}|${s.model}`;
       let new_vehicle = new Vehicle(`${s.year}`, `${s.make}`, `${s.model}`, `${s.trim}`, `${s.price}`, `${url}`, `${s.cl_url}`, `${s.cl_location}`);
       return new_vehicle;
  });
```

I extract the URL's in the following code snippet and use axios.all to request data from each one.

```
      let urls = vehicle_data.map(function(m) {
    return m.url;
  })

  let options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': {
      'Host': 'marketcheck-prod.apigee.net'
    }
  };

  axios.all(urls.map(url => {
    request(url, options, function (error, response, body) { 
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }))
```

**My Problem:**

I am using a 3rd Party API (Marcketcheck) - Holds data on vehicles.

The response data comes back (See below as an example. This is data for just 1 url)

```
{"price_stats":{"geometric_mean":3413,"min":899,"median":3595,"population_standard_deviation":1323,"variance":1750285,"ax":7995,"mean":3655,"trimmed_mean":3572,"standard_deviation":1323,"iqr":1800},"miles_stats":{"geometric_mean":97901,"min":2,"median":125000,"population_standard_deviation":51713,"variance":2147483647,"max":230456,"mean":125182,"trimmed_mean":125879,"standard_deviation":51713,"iqr":74734},"dom_stats":{"geometric_mean":100,"min":1,"median":100,"population_standard_deviation":399,"variance":159152,"max":2513,"mean":247,"trimmed_mean":162,"standard_deviation":399,"iqr":217},"count":101}
```

I cannot figure out how to match up each response data to the vehicle object of that specific url.

For example, if I request 3 urls from the vehicle object. Let's name them:

1. Url-1
2. Url-2
3. Url-3

I get my response data back as objects:

1. OBJ-1
2. OBJ-2
3. OBJ-3

I have no way as far as I know with my level of knowledge, how to assign each object back to it's specific URL and THEN, match up that OBJ data with it's specific vehicle.

I haven been beating my head against a wall for about 4 days, I cannot figure this out.

Any suggestions are welcome and I really appreciate anybody looking at this post to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
    let requests = urls.map((url) => {
      return axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          'Host': 'marketcheck-prod.apigee.net'
        }
      });
    });   

    Promise.all(requests).then((responces) => {
       console.log(responces);
    }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
    });
```